# Why doesn't OSX Activity Monitor show the processes I started?

Tags: c++, macos, process, fork, execv

I'm using fork and execv to start child processes. If I run htop then I can find those processes. However, OSX Activity Monitor doesn't show them, even if I have it set to show all processes. Why is that?

The S column in htop show Z for all of my processes. What does that mean? Could that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The Z in htop means the process is a "zombie". This means that the process has completed running and wants to die, but the parent process has not yet called `wait()` to obtain the child process exit code.

It's possible that the OS X Activity Monitor does not show zombie processes.

Comment: So these spawned programs don't just exit by themselves?

Comment: They do exit by themselves, but normally the parent will want to be able to find out what *exit code* the process returned with. This is only possible if the PID remains allocated *to that process* until the parent can find out what the exit code was. Zombie processes go away when either (a) the parent calls `wait()` for the zombie in question, or (b) the parent dies.

Comment: If you use `wait()`, then does that stop execution of the parent process until the child process exits?

Comment: Yes, for `wait()`. But it sounds like you want to use the related `waitpid()` function. See the `WNOHANG` flag to `waitpid()`.